# How did people transverse through the LinkedIn password file so fast?

Tags: c++, large-files

I've obtained the file and it is 258 MB (unzipped) There were already sites able to confirm if a hashed password was in the list by 2:00 PM the day the file was released. I obtained it last night, and wrote a short C++ program to read the file line by line and insert it into MySQL

```
ifstream fin ("c:/xampp/htdocs/combo_not.txt");
string    myStr;

while(getline(fin, myStr))  
  {                    

 mysql_query(conn, ("INSERT INTO passwords(password) VALUES('" + myStr + "')").c_str());   

  }
```

I realize this question may be downvoted ( or even closed) But It is a real question that I would like an answer for. How does one transverse a file so large within a small time frame? You can't open the file in Notepad and press `CTR F` and search that way because the program will run out of memory. So far my table has just under 1 million recordsl, and the c++ console program has been running for about 12 or more hours by now.

Comment: I think the bigger question is HOW DID THEY GET THE PASSWORDS????

Comment: Well the passwords were avaliable from a multitude of servers once word got out that a zipped file was leaked.

Comment: And linkedin didnt salt the passwords and there exists ready rainbow tables for common hash formats. So finding the easy and even harder passwords is very fast.

Comment: no, I'm asking how was the site hacked? INITIALLY

Comment: Are you running a debug build..?

Comment: also if you need to insert stuff into a database fast, you use something like COPY FROM and or insert them in one huge transaction to avoid overhead.

Comment: @frenchie I have no idea. I just know that I have the password file on my Box supposedly there is supposed to be 6.5 million UNIQUE passwords in the list

Comment: you can easily use a unix commandline "sort" to sort a file of that size in a relatively short time. after they are sorted , a binary search will take log2(lines) operations to answer if something exists on the list or not.

Comment: ha wow. I guess i shouldn't have built a database of the hashes then. I was going to use the database to see if my password was actually in the list ( I already changed it )

Comment: @frenchie: I haven't found any stories yet that describe the hack itself. Given how embarrassing it is for LinkedIn that they stored unsalted password hashes, I would not be surprised if the hack was equally embarrassing. But your multiple question marks suggest that you are surprised they got hacked -- this kind of thing happens every day, and whether a given hack makes the news doesn't have much to do with whether the attack itself is technically interesting. Most exploitable flaws are some silly oversight by someone, not necessarily at LinkedIn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
echo sha1("password")
?>
```

**Open up a command promt and type this command:**

```
sort hacked.txt /o sorted_data.txt
```

**After the file was sorted, then type this command in**

```
findstr "string" sorted_data.txt
```

If your password is in the list it will print out in the terminal.
if your password was not in the list, then try replacing the first five(5) with a "0"  characters Surprisingly, my password was in the list

Answer (score 2):

you use indexes.. binary search and hashing are very, very fast.

Comment: also the sites probably just answer "yes" to every password stupid people write and then go 0wn their account..

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has [autocommit enabled](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) by default.  That means you are starting and committing a transaction, which includes a disk write and flush, for every single row.

Set autocommit off with:

```
mysql_autocommit(conn, 0);
```

before the loop, then call:

```
mysql_commit(conn);
```

after the loop.

Comment: I'm reading about autocommit, something I wasn't aware of. Should I turn autocommit off when I have a script that performs updates on a table with 5,000 rows?

Comment: @RPM, generally.  However, you should also consider the concept of a unit of work.  Do you want the change to each row to immediately and permanently take effect (transaction per row/autocommit)?  Or do you want the changes to take effect only if they all succeed (explicit transaction around all the updates)?  The second will have better performance, but that's useless if it's performing the wrong thing.  If you use an explicit transaction, and for example, the last update fails, they will all rollback.  Of course, this may be rare in your circumstances.

Comment: Yes. The change should be immediately and permanent in effect. I don't see how they wouldn't succeed. Right now The script takes about 3 minutes. to perform the updates

Comment: @RPM, if it takes only 3 minutes, it's probably a minor point for now.  The question boils down to what you want to happen if it fails partway through the rows (after 2500, 4999, whatever).  It's probably unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

They probably didn't try to insert passwords into the database, or didn't try to insert passwords into the database with clustered index on the hashed password itself.